# Issue in accessing the output using generator functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, yield

I have the below code, I need to use one tuple of the data retrieved from the CSV file at a time perform some action and then move to the next tuple when again the step function is called. I don't understand how to use the obs variable. When I retrieve I get a generator object. Help is highly appreciated thanks.

```
  def get_state(self):
    def createGenerator(self):
     obs_data = [tuple(x) for x in self.data[['value_1']], 
           'value_2']].to_numpy()]
     for obs in obs_data:
        yield obs

  def step(self):
    ob = self.get_state()
```

Comment: You could do something like `for o in ob: …`. But using a generator seems a little pointless the way the code is written now. You're collecting data into a list, iterating over it and then yielding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're not returning anything in the outer method, only the inner generator function.
2. You never call the inner function to actual create the generator.

I can't tell exactly what you're asking for, but here is code that will run:

```py
def get_state(self):
    def createGenerator():
       obs_data = [tuple(x) for x in self.data[['value_1']], 
           'value_2']].to_numpy()]
       for obs in obs_data:
          yield obs
    if self.gen is None:
        self.gen = createGenerator()
    return next(self.gen)

def step(self):
    ob = self.get_state()
```

You should use `next()` to get the value, or you can use a for loop and treat the generator as a iterable.

Comment: @emandavis I'm not sure what your question is, are you getting an error?

Comment: @M Z, when I run the above code after putting it in a class and creating an object. 
I get an error 'Environment2' object has no attribute 'gen'

Comment: initialize `self.gen` as `None` in your `__init__`. There'll be a couple other debug things you'll probably have to do in order to make it seamless. This is just a starting point since I don't know everything you have

Comment: Sorry I have sorted out the issue. Thank you for your help its working like a charm

Comment: I would like to ask that when I run the above code every time it gives the same tuple. If I need to move to the next move I have to call the env.get_state() again. Any suggestion if I call env.get_state() once and every time it must give a different tuple from the CSV file.

Comment: sorry, could you clarify that again? `env.step()` should have a different `ob` each time you call it

Comment: Yes, each time when  env.step method is called it must return different value not the same each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219701/discussion-between-m-z-and-eman-davis).